# Relaxing the parallel lines assumption in a proportional odds model

Tags: stata, nonlinear-regression

I tried to specify a partial proportional odds regression in STATA using the [`gologit2` command.](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0097)

However, `gologit2` runs [extraordinarily slow](https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/gologit2/tsfaq.html) in my dataset (108k observations of 9 vars). For example,

```
ologit PfSt age if bund == 1
```

runs in less than 1 sec, while

```
gologit2 PfSt age if bund == 1, pl
```

which is [essentially the same](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/g/gologit2.html), as the `pl` option enforces parallel lines in all vars, i.e., the `ologit` specification, takes about a minute on my computer.

Calculating the fully specified model is possible with `ologit` and `mlogit` (~ 1 min), but not with `gologit2`, even if I specify for which variables parallel lines should be assumed. 
The regression command is

```
ologit PfSt age age_sq gender i.bundesland tt tt2 [fw=size], cluster(bundesland)
```

where `PfSt` ranges from 0 to 7 and `tt` capture time trends (`tt = year − 1996` and `tt2 = -1/tt +1`, a “phasing out” trend)

Now, considering that relaxing the parallel lines assumption for some variables would be identical to adding interaction terms to my model specification, I could change my regression command to

`ologit PfSt age* gender i.bundesland#i.PfSt tt*, cluster(bundesland)` would yield me different coefficients per level of `PfSt` for the one variable for which I would relax the parallel lines assumption. **Is that correct?**

*However*, the estimation process **fails to converge**, as now (1200th iteration) negative log pseudoelikelihood ratios rise (i.e., drop in absolute values, now <<0.0001), but they are `(non concave)`. I wonder **why is this the case?**, as both `ologit` and `mlogit` did produce results after a few iterations.